# How do I package a Facelets composite component for use in another web app?

Tags: jsf, facelets

Let's say I've created a simple composite component in one of my JSF 2.0 web applications using Facelets.  Now, I want to use that component in another webapp.  Rather than copy the .xhtml file from one app to another, I would like to create a library that I can simply include in each of the webapps.

How do I package my composite components to make a library that can be shared across projects?

Comment: I made a minor edit: a composite component actually isn't JSF-specific, it's Facelets-specific :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a post to the webtier mailing list I was told that the jar file must have a META-INF/faces-config.xml file that has a root faces-config element with a version of 2.0.  After creating that, the webapp was able to reference my custom composite components.

Mailing list thread [here](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=70822&tstart=0)

Comment: You got answer of one of the Facelets main developers Jason Lee, so I would really consider it as valid :) It's nice that you posted it here as well.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  I spent plenty of time on your blog when I was learning jsf 1.1 and 1.2.  As for posting here, I figure if it took me all morning to find the answer, hopefully I can keep someone else from that fate.